# Series with time-traveling scientists who collect prehistoric creatures

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I have seen a series where a team of scientists made a portal with two science-fiction sticks that gave them the ability to go back in time to the year of their wish, and they took prehistoric creatures back to their camp which was a sort of zoo. They got a mammoth and made it live with elephants.

In the first couple of episodes they go back to the Ice Age and in later episodes they go back to the time of dinosaurs.

Comment: A portal that gave them the abbility to go back in time and.. *

Comment: When did you read it?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152714/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: is this a book or television series? When did you see it? What country, what language, etc.... see @Edlothiad's links and you'll likely have somebody figure it out

Comment: The first thing that popped into my head was Syfy's _Primeval_.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [Prehistoric Park](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0760139/). The [second episode](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x56bkew_prehistoric-park-e02-a-mammoth-undertaking_tech) dealt with mammoths. His 'time-portal' was basically two metal uprights controlled with a garage opener.

> Nigel Marven travels back in time to rescue exotic creatures on the
>   brink of extinction. CGI is used to create animals no longer seen on
>   earth, from woolly mammoths, and T Rex, to dinosaur-eating crocodiles.